# Wordpress loop with new. args for else

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, if-statement

I would like to show posts in a custom post type with the category 'pin-post-to-homepage', then if that doesn't exist then display posts from a different post type.

Below are the arguments. Feel like I am very close, as the first query works when a post has the category, though the second loop isn't working at the moment. Are the args added to the else correctly?

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    $first_args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'timeline', 
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'pin',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'pin-post-to-homepage',
            )
        ),
    );  
    
    $second_args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'days',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'rand'
    );      


    $first_query = new WP_Query($first_args);
    if ($first_query->have_posts()) {
        while ( $first_query->have_posts() ) {
            $first_query->the_post();
    ?>

        <?php get_template_part('partials/andSoOnTimeline'); ?>

    
    <?php
        }
    } else {
      $second_query = new WP_Query($second_args);
      if ($second_query->have_posts() ){
    ?>

    

        <?php get_template_part('partials/days'); ?>


<?php
    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: You may need to call `wp_reset_postdata()` as described here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#more-information. Try to call the function after you have processed everything related to the `$first_query` and `$second_query`. If this doesn't fix your issue it's still good practices to ensure there are no future WP loops that are "out of sync"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$first_query = new WP_Query($first_args);
$has_results = false;
if ($first_query->have_posts()) {
    $has_results = true;
    while ( $first_query->have_posts() ) {
       $first_query->the_post();
       get_template_part('partials/andSoOnTimeline');
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
if ($has_results === false) {
    $second_query = new WP_Query($second_args);
      if ($second_query->have_posts() ){
          //Update line below since first post
          $second_query->the_post();
          //...
      }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: thanks @AndersRehn This is close. In testing, the second query will run if the first one isn't true, however it won't get the the content from my partial page named 'days'. In days, I use toolset types to get the custom fields from the post `types_render_field`—this is what is not showing up. Do you know why the content wouldnt show?

Comment: Just to ensure I got it correct. Does your code enter the if-clause `if ($second_query->have_posts() )` and executes `get_template_part('partials/days');` but with wrong data or is `get_template_part('partials/days');` never called?

Comment: thats correct, I included the code exactly as you have above, and replaced the `//...` with `get_template_part('partials/days');` It would appear that it does call `get_template_part('partials/days');` correctly, however it wont get the content from the posts.

For example, in `get_template_part('partials/days');` I have `<figure><?php echo do_shortcode( '[types field="home-single-image-landscape-format" size="large"]' ); ?></figure>` and the result is just the empty figure tags.

Comment: are you calling `$second_query->the_post();` before calling the `get_template_part('...')`?

Comment: ah! of course, thats what is missing. thank you for that, I missed it before.

Comment: out of curiosity, would this method allow a `$third_query` as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236386/discussion-between-r-g-and-andersrehn).